# Makefile for JNI invocation not working - undefined reference to JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: java, c, makefile, java-native-interface

I have a makeifile with a task as follows. When I compile, I get a linker error, but I'm not sure why since I"m linking / including to the java libs. I verified that $JAVA_HOME exists and the libjvm.so exists in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server`

make error:

```
(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

makefile:

```
my_program:
    gcc -L${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server/ \
    -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/ \
    -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux/ \
    -ljvm \
    my_program.c
run: my_program
   ./a.out
```

c fiel:

```
#include <jni.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
     printf("hello\n");
     return 0;
}


JNIEnv *create_vm(JavaVM **jvm){
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;
//  options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=" JAVA_PROG_PATH;
//  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_7;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
    char *failed = "nothing";
    if(ret < 0){
        goto create_vm_error;

    }
    return env;

    lookup_error:
        dlog(0, "Error looking up class or method %s.\n", failed);
        (**jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(*jvm);
    create_vm_error:
        *jvm = NULL;
        return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stupid as it sounds - move -ljmv to after my_program.c:

```
my_program:
    gcc -L${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server/ \
    -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/ \
    -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux/ \
    my_program.c \
    -ljvm
run: my_program
   ./a.out
```

This is a common error that happens because GCC requires that your compilation unit (`my_program.c`) be provided before the library specification (yes, the compilation unit should be strictly to the left of the libraries) so it can tell which symbols it needs from that library. If the order is reversed, gcc deducts there are no needed symbols and the library will not be used...

If I had a penny for every time this happened to me

Comment: OK, that got me further. I was able to build my a.out. however, whenI go to run it, I get an error about the .so not being found. 

`./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: For an easy fix, copy `libjvm.so` to the same directory you're running `a.out`. For the full gore explanation on why this happens (spoiler: because libjvm.so is not in a directory your loader was instructed to search in) look here: http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html

Comment: Alright, i'm trying to figure out how to add a copy command to my makefile

Comment: even when I manually copy the libjvm.so and try to run a.out, I get the erro about libjvm.so missing still.

Comment: Try running your code like this:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server;./a.out`. Please read the link I gave to understand what you're doing and why its potentially bad

Comment: That command doesn't work. However, I apparently can run a.out with the .so file locally. i just dont know how to copy the file as part of the make file

Comment: OK, not sure why it wasn' twokring, but I was able to do thias my cp command: cp ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so .

Comment: OK, it's running, but when I go to launch the JVM, I get a complaint about libjava.so not being found. ARGH

Comment: You're getting these errors because the path in which libjava.so and libjvm.so are not in the loader path. See here how to fix this: https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html

Comment: I'm still lost on what i'm supposed to change in my makefile. gcc isn't understanding -R or -rpath flags.

Comment: I even tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH outside of my makefile, so it's permanently set, but teh system doesn't seem to search the paths for the .so files.

Comment: @StealthRabbi Hi, did you find solution to this? I am stuck on this from past 2 days. Can you help?